# Post method cannot be delivered

Tags: python, django

I decided to change the topic of my learning logs.

[image]

When I press the submit button, it fails to redirect and reports 479 error.

```
[15/May/2018 12:46:32] "POST /edit_topic/5 HTTP/1.1" 200 479
```

**edit_topic.html**

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

    {% block content %}
        <p>
            <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a>
        </p>
        <p>Edit The Entry:</p>
        <form  action="{% url "learning_logs:edit_topic" topic.id %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button name="button">save changes</button>

        </form>

    {% endblock content %}
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Topic, Entry

class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text':''}
```

**views.py**

```
def edit_topic(request, topic_id):
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)

    if request != "POST":
        form = TopicForm(instance=topic)
        print(request) # test point
    else:
        form = TopicForm(instance=topic, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("learning_logs:topic", args=[topic_id]))

    context = {'topic':topic, 'form':form}
    print(form) # test form 
    return render(request, "learning_logs/edit_topic.html", context)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    #Home Page
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    # Show all the topics
    url(r'^topics/$', views.topics, name='topics'),
    # Detail pate for a single topics
    url(r'^topic/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$', views.topic, name='topic'),
    # Page for adding a new topic
    url(r'^new_topic/$', views.new_topic, name='new_topic'),
    # Page for editing the topic
    url(r'^edit_topic/(?P<topic_id>\d+)$', views.edit_topic, name='edit_topic'),
    # page for adding a new Entry
    url(r"^new_entry/(?P<topic_id>\d+)$", views.new_entry, name='new_entry'),
    # page for adding a edit  Entry
    url(r"^edit_entry/(?P<entry_id>\d+)$", views.edit_entry, name="edit_entry"),
]
```

**models.py**

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about."""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.text
```

What's the problem with my code?

When I try to submit, there's no error, but the changes aren't submitted.

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 15, 2018 - 13:01:44
Django version 1.11.13, using settings 'learning_log.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8001/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[15/May/2018 13:01:48] "POST /edit_topic/4 HTTP/1.1" 200 475
```

Comment: there's no 479 error. your http response is `200` ok.  please give more information about error.

Comment: there's no error report, it did not process my submitted data and redirect. @seuling

Comment: check your error with `form_invalid()`. you have `if` statement with `form_valid()`. Make else statement and `print(form.errors)` for debug- you always have to check which error occured in form

Comment: it still does not report error

Comment: Then I guess your form is valid. then the problem is in form itself i think.. Can you use debug like ipython embed? `pip install ipython` and add `from ipython import embed; embed()` below (or above) `form.save()` and submit - then you can see ipython embed in your runserver shell.

Comment: ty, it's not the problem, I try it tomorrow.

Comment: OK. anyway, if you're using form, I recommend using `FormView` or `CreateView`. (In your case `UpdateView`). I guess in your situation, you don't need to using form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view, the condition is wrong

```
if request != "POST" # this will be always true
```

it should be

```
if request.method != "POST"
```